# How to create a Full RSS feed (secret URL) for certain users, short for the rest

Tags: rss, membership, premium

I'm running a Patreon campaign for my blog and **one of the rewards will be a full RSS** available for users that contribute to that campaign, with the rest having only a short RSS Feed.

I'm experimenting with the [SB RSS Feed Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sb-rss-feed-plus/screenshots/) plugin, but I've just installed it and I'm not sure it will do what I ask. I wonder if there is an alternative to get what I want, specifically:

**A special, secret URL for the full RSS feed**

I know there are services that can provide the full RSS feed from the short one (I guess it's impossible to block them) but anyway, I'd like to set that full RSS feed as a "premium" advantage for Patreon supporters. I wouldn't like to implemente a Membership to my blog (I think this overcomplicates everything) and I'd like if this is possible easily.

Comment: As the plugin description states it can create "Full-text RSS Feed when accessed via special URL" which is as I understand what you need. Is there something else that you need and this plugin can't do?

Comment: close voted as you are asking for plugin recomendations which are off-topic, but this should be a 10-20 line thing if you just try.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic. Maybe [this approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/195197/26350) to control the feed length via a GET parameter, can help you writing your own plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A "secret" full text feed

Here's a demo plugin that gives you a full text feed at:

```
example.tld/secretfeed/
```

Just remember to flush the rewrite rules, e.g. by visiting the *Settings/Permalinks* page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Secret Full Text Feed
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208724/26350
 */
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    add_feed( 'secretfeed', 'do_feed_rss2' );
});

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $q->is_feed( 'secretfeed' ) )
        add_filter( 'option_rss_use_excerpt', '__return_false' );

} );
```

You can then adjust the `secretfeed` slug to your needs.

Comment: The secret is out, now the feed isn't "safe" anymore, it lost the element of surprice, hahahaha. ;-)

Comment: hehe damn, I should have encrypt it;-) @PieterGoosen