# How to get feed for pages?

Tags: feed

I have a question about WordPress feeds.

I know that the default feed:

```
http://www.example.com/feed/
```

is for the `post` post type.

However, I would like to create a new feed, only for the `page` post type, e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/kellyspagefeed/
```

I don't want to override the default one.

Can anyone give me a direction on **how to get feed for pages**?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom feed that's accessible from here:

```
example.tld/kellyspagefeed/
```

and only shows *pages* instead of *posts*.

We could try to rewrite the recent answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208713/how-to-create-a-full-rss-feed-secret-url-for-certain-users-short-for-the-rest/208724#208724), with the following demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Kelly's Page Feed
 * Description: Accessible from the /kellyspagefeed slug
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209244/26350
 */

// Add the custom rss2 feed   
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_init' );

// Set the 'page' post type for the custom feed
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( \WP_Query $q )
{
    if( $q->is_feed( 'kellyspagefeed' ) )
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'page' );
} );

// Add our rewrite rules and flush only during plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_init' );

// House cleaning during plugin deactivation - remove our rewrite rules
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );

// Helper function
function wpse_init()
{
    add_feed( 'kellyspagefeed', 'do_feed_rss2' );

    if( 'init' !== current_filter() )
        flush_rewrite_rules();  
}
```

Let's note that this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

will not work here, because we have to flush the rewrite rules **after** we've  added our custom feed rewrite rules with `add_feed()`.

So that's why I introduced the `wp_init()` helper function:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_init' );
```

where we make sure the rewrite rules are not flushed within the `init` hook. That flush is expensive so we only want to do it when our demo plugin is activated or deactivated.

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs,