# How to Change Default RSS Feed URL in WordPress Website?

Tags: plugins, urls, rss, static-website

I have a news website and have RSS enabled. Some people fetching posts from my RSS feed to their website. Can anyone help me remove the default rss url which is like "website.com/feed" and add a new unqiue RSS URL so that my competitors are unable to find the rss?

Comment: Maybe this variation can help https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208724/26350. But its easy to scrape sites for content so hiding rss feed will not do much.